# Change value from 1 To Yes In MySQL select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm only able to SELECT on a table.

The table has a column called inty with a value of 0 or 1

I am currently selecting inty as:

```
SELECT inty AS InternetApproved FROM Table1
```

Is there a way to reformat the data within the SQL SELECT so that if the value is 0 make it No and if the value is 1 make it Yes for display purposes in the output SELECT results?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simple and easy way to achieve this  is:

```
SELECT IF(inty = 1, 'YES', 'No') AS internetApproved FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN inty = 0 then 'No'
    WHEN inty = 1 then 'Yes'
    ELSE 'Maybe'
END
AS InternetApproved
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select case when inty  = 0 then 'no' else 'yes' end as newcolname from table1;
```